# MonoDevelop: Format of Code preferences

Tags: mono, monodevelop

In MonoDevelop (Mac) I wish to have the code formatter-cleaner (Shift_Control_f) leave the line breaks in code.

For example:

```
var x =  ABC.EDF
         .Save()
```

gets re-written as

```
var x =  ABC.EDF.Save()
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you file a bug report on MonoDevelop to request that this option be added to code formatting preferences.

Comment: I think that is a good idea. With c# and Linq our code lines are huge. Breaking them into multi lines makes the code more readable